# url.action for auto-complete

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

After help from the reply I changed my code to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(per => per.Hospital, new { style = "width:220px", @maxlength = "50", data_autocomplete = Url.Action("HospitalList", "Person") })
```

My jquery is

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    $('input[data_autocomplete]').each(function () {
        var url = $(this).data('autocomplete');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.getJSON(url, {
                    term: request.term
                }, response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And a created a new Action result

```
 public ActionResult HospitalList(string term)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        result.Add("Hospital 1");
        result.Add("NYUMC");
        result.Add("Christ");
        result.Add("Bellevue");
        result.Add("NewYork-Presbyterian");
        result.Add("North Central Bronx Hospital");            

        return Json(result , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

now where am i going wromg. All I see a a text box , no behavior of auto complete. Should i be including any jquery library for it to work

Comment: What are you using for auto complete? jQuery UI?

Comment: I am not using anything I am just trying to get textboxfor behave as auto complete. I am very new to MVC and jquery. All that I have done is listed above.

Comment: There's no autocomplete functionality in `HTML`. If you want to use one you will have to use a plugin. jQuery UI autocomplete is such a plugin. You need to reference jquery.js and `jquery-ui.js` in your view. You should also definitely read a little bit of documentation to familiarize yourself with some basic javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown which autocomplete plugin you are using. If it is the [`jQuery UI autocomplete`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) you could return the filtered results as JSON from your controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PersonSearch(string term)
{
    // The term parameter will contain the value entered by the user in the textbox.
    // here you could use it and query your database in order to filter the results.
    string[] result = new string[]
    {
        "filtered value 1",
        "filtered value 2",
        "filtered value 3",
        "filtered value 4",
    };

    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And finally you would attach the plugin:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[data-autocomplete]').each(function() {
        var url = $(this).data('autocomplete');
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.getJSON(url, {
                    term: request.term
                }, response);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Notice how the controller action takes the `term` parameter and should return a list of strings as JSON.

Comment: Hello Darin thanks for the reply. If yous see my controller above i am returning a view now based on what you explained I have to return jason how can i return view and jason together. I was not using any autocomplete plugins.

Comment: You cannot return JSON and a view at the same time. This doesn't make sense. In order to use the jQuery UI autocomplete plugin make sure that you have included first `jquery.js` and then `jquery-ui.js` scripts to your page. Finally you could use the `.autocomplete` in your custom script.